# Packing two characters to an integer

Tags: c

I have written a code to pack two characters to an integer; which should output in both decimal and binary formats.

The code compiled successfully, but the problem is, after I enter the first character `character1` it is not asking me to enter `character2` , rather it is directly going on itself and reaching the end of the code. I tried adding `getch()` after entering `character1`, but no use. I am new to this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void displayInBitFormat(char character);
void packCharacters(char character1, char character2 );
char character1, character2;

int main(void){

    puts("Enter the first character");
    scanf("%c",&character1);

    printf("\n%c's bit representation is: \n",character1);
    displayInBitFormat(character1); 

    printf("Enter the second character");
    scanf("%c",&character2);

    getch(); // TRIED ADDING THIS

    printf("\n%c's bit representation is: \n",character2);
    displayInBitFormat(character2);

    puts("");

    packCharacters(character1,character2);

    getch();

}

void packCharacters(char character1, char character2){

    unsigned c;

    c=character1; // assigning first character with unsigned

    c=c<<8; // shifting first char to 8 bits left
    c=c|character2; //bitwise inclusive OR 

    printf("After packing characters, Result in binary is: \n");
    displayInBitFormat(c);
    puts("\nResult in decimal number is: ");
    printf("%u", c);

}

//bit representer of an int
void displayInBitFormat(char character){

    unsigned int i;//counter


    unsigned int displayMask=1<<31;
    printf("%10u=",character);

    for (i=1;i<=32;++i)
    {
        putchar(character&displayMask ? '1':'0');

        character<<=1; 
        if (i%8==0){
        putchar(' ');
    }
}
putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note, as you're posting on here we already assume that your code isn't working. Please don't prefix your question with "code not working".

Comment: In UTF-8 (and other encodings) a character can be substantially more than a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%c",&character2);
```

picks up the newline character that was left on the input stream when you read the first character.

Change it to:

```
scanf(" %c",&character2);
```

**Update** In response to the comment by @user3615120

Let's say you entered `a` and `Enter` when you wanted to read the first character. At that time, the input stream has two characters in it: `'a'` and `'\n'`. When the line

```
scanf("%c",&character1);
```

gets executed, `'a'` is read and stored in `character1`. The `'\n'` is still left in the input stream.

When

```
scanf("%c",&character2);
```

is executed, the `'\n'` is read and stored in `character2`. When you change that line to

```
scanf(" %c",&character2);
```

the white spaces that are left in the stream is discarded. The first non-whitespace character is read and stored in `character2`.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Thank you. But I didn't quite get the explanation. If you don't mind could you please elaborate it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

One other possible approach using `getchar()` is to manually eat the `\n` with another call to `getchar()`. Also, your `displayInBitFormat` needs to take a wider type than `char` if you are going to use it to print the combined expression.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayInBitFormat(unsigned int character);
void packCharacters(char character1, char character2 );
int character1, character2;

int main(void){
    puts("Enter the first character");
    character1 = getchar();

    // Eat the newline that came from reading the first character.
    getchar();

    printf("\n%c's bit representation is: \n",character1);
    displayInBitFormat(character1); 

    printf("Enter the second character");
    character2 = getchar();

    printf("\n%c's bit representation is: \n",character2);
    displayInBitFormat(character2);
    puts("");
    packCharacters(character1,character2);
}

void packCharacters(char character1, char character2){

    unsigned int c;

    c=character1; // assigning first character with unsigned

    c=c<<8; // shifting first char to 8 bits left
    c=c|character2; //bitwise inclusive OR 

    printf("After packing characters, Result in binary is: \n");
    displayInBitFormat(c);
    puts("\nResult in decimal number is: ");
    printf("%u\n", c);
}

//bit representer of an int
void displayInBitFormat(unsigned int character){

    unsigned int i;//counter

    unsigned int displayMask=1<<31;
    printf("%10u=",character);

    for (i=1;i<=32;++i)
    {
        putchar(character&displayMask ? '1':'0');

        character<<=1; 
        if (i%8==0){
        putchar(' ');
    }
}
putchar('\n');
}
```